# How to do sum of multiple columns and print in one column in rtf template of BIP report

Tags: oracle11g, report, formula, rtf, bi-publisher

I want to merge three columns in one column and print their sum into that column
These columns are printing amounts

Currently I am tryin this formula but it is giving 0 in all places.

Comment: <?sum(current-group()/column_1) + sum(current-group()/column_2) + sum(current-group()/column_3)?> this I tried but giving 0 values

Comment: Please provide a data sample and what you expect the output to look like.